# Virtual Machines Network

Tags: azure

In the new portal I created several new VM's.
During deployment I can get an option to create a stand alone machine or connect to another machine.
But whatever choice I make there is no connectivity between the machines.

Is is possible to connect them to the same VMnwetwork/VLAN?

I want to test two servers in a setup in which they communicate with each other.

Comment: This question isn't about programming and would be more at home on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have 2 options here:

- [Create a Virtual Network](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/add-a-vm-to-a-virtual-network/)
- [Add the VM in an existing Cloud Service](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/connect-to-a-cloud-service/) (mainly used for load balancing)

Note that pinging might not work without opening a port on the Windows Firewall ([source](http://blogs.biztalk360.com/windows-azure-virtual-machines-virtual-network-may-not-ping-automatically/))